# Where is the .env file stored for php

Tags: php, getenv

In some laravel the .env-file is heavily used to store the application configuration values. I am currently playing with a legacy project of mine and in a cronjob I am developing, I planned on testing out using .env to store information.

Question is: is there a "simple" way to use this .env file?

Comment: php.ini = php configuration

Comment: Is there even a `.env` file for PHP? If you want to use one I guess you'd need to use the `dotEnv` package or similar

Comment: Show hidden files.

Comment: You can use .env with composer

Comment: @brombeer - if you could write this as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to feedback from those who commented I ended up using the dotEnv package. This worked smoothly.

The package can be found here:

https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

**Here are some links related to using environment variables in PHP:**

https://blog.doppler.com/configuring-php-applications-using-environment-variables
https://www.twilio.com/blog/working-with-environment-variables-in-php
https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643130/using-environment-variables-in-php

**From the PHP manual**

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php